# How do I use mockito to test JPA methods?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, mockito

I recently learned and have been using Mockito for the past two months but faced a roadblock. I have created a query that filters for various complex conditions and I would like to test the behavior and functionality based on given inputs.

With Mockito, we can mock and define the return value but I just want to allow the filter to do its work. The problem I have is how exactly should I go about this? Is there some way to mock a database and its rows so I can allow my filter to take course and validate my filter's functionality?

Any guidance or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you
:)

Comment: Sounds to my like you want an integration test instead of an unit test. With an integration test you can spin up an inmemory database to communicate with. You can than insert the test data you need in the @Before of your test. So you dont need to mock the database but connect to a inmemory database just for the tests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented by @Willem, it's strongly recommended to have more realistic test, even not against some In-Memory DB like H2, but real Docker/Sql-engine (like for MySql:  `ch.vorburger.mariadb4j.DB.newEmbeddedDB(DBConfigurationBuilder.newBuilder().build()).start())`). This will ensure the real SQLs will be tested. There are some differences between real DB engine and the In-Memory, that you'd like to discover before deploying.

Anyway, if you'd like to have it mocked, you can do:

```
// in the @Before
SomeJpaRepository someRepo = Mockito.mock(SomeJpaRepository.class);
ReflectionTestUtils.setField(someService, "someJpsRepo", someRepo);

// in the @Test 
Mockito.when(someRepo.saveAll(ArgumentMatchers.any())).thenReturn(new ArrayList<>());
Mockito.when(someRepo.getRecordsByFilter(request, PageRequest.of(0, 100))).thenReturn(getMockAnswer());
```

Now, when I'm reading again your question: "*I have created a query that filters...*" I think you cannot do it with a mock, as you'd like to test the SQL itself. To achieve this you can insert the test rows from a CSV.